# Error on get record in Rails Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-activerecord

When o try verify in my helper if my database have the record this stop on the verifier whit this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in FinancesController#index

Couldn't find Place with id=5
```

Im using this helper:

```
  def get_acc_name(acc_id)
    @var = Place.find(acc_id)
    if @var.kind_of?(Array)
    @var = @var.place 
    else
    @var = "(Deletado)"
    end
    return @var
  end
```

The problem is the script stop on the first line and font make a if else, i dont know how i solve this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use where instead of find. find raises exception if a record is not found. So, use this instead:

```
@var = Place.where(:id => acc_id).first
```

or

```
@var = Place.find_by_id(acc_id)
```

They will not raise exception. :)

Comment: Thanks im solver using the find_by_id and the verify a simple if @var, thanks for help.